# Generate data from Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: distributions, reliability, dirichlet-distribution

I want to generate Dirichlet distributed data, but I don't know how to do it. Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you add some more detail & context? I'm not sure your question is answerable at present.

Comment: It seems quite apparent that the OP is asking how to generate pseudo-random numbers for a random variable having a Dirichlet distribution.  Therefore I suggest you take this question off hold.

Answer (score 3):

you can use R and `gtools` package, function is `rdirichlet(n, alpha)`. Or just copy and paste code below to make `rdirichlet(n, alpha)`function without installing a new package,

```
rdirichlet<-function (n, alpha) 
{
    l <- length(alpha)
    x <- matrix(rgamma(l * n, alpha), ncol = l, byrow = TRUE)
    sm <- x %*% rep(1, l)
    x/as.vector(sm)
}
```

Comment: The question does not refer to R and does not ask for R code. It is a good example but your answer lacks description of how and why this could be achieved. Not everyone here is R-literate.

Comment: You could also read the question as saying that the op would be happy with any type of guidance. As @gung correctly said, it's rather (too) vague as it stands

Comment: I think the question was pretty clear: "How can I generate Dirichlet distributed data?". And isn't this *exactly* an answer to that question?